# Angular 14 lighthouse fix Avoid chaining critical request

Tags: lighthouse, angular14, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I have an Angular 14 Application, my manager is insisting to fix all lighthouse diagnostics, but for
Avoid chaining critical request I am not finding any solution to fix it . I have attached screenshot of the issue from lighthouse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woQsE.png)

I have done lazy loading to keep my main bundle small and I have research on this issue but not finding any solution is there a way to fix this

I have used lazy loading, dynamic import and also used webpack-bundle-analyzer , below is the screenshot of my my bundle analyzer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un5LV.png)